# How to fix node-gyp error during npm installation

Tags: npm, node-gyp

I have an issue running npm install.

Node Version: v11.8.0
MacOS: 10.14.1

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@11.8.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile withnode-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4--node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/YOUR_USER/Coding/arrow_gui/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 48412 packages in 20.86s
found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried running npm audit fix, but nothing useful turned up so far.

I tried looking for solutions on the web, but so far nothing has helped me thus far.

EDIT:
I would like to know how come anaconda3 python installation is being pulled into this compilation error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you still get this errors ?

This errors occurred since `fsevents` package depending on the old version of nodejs. Downgrade your nodejs version into `10.15.1` (lts/dubnium) , then you can get rid this error.

additional: you can install and switch between various nodejs version using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)